# i want to remove the Carousel arrows and indicators if there is only one

Tags: javascript, css, dom, bootstrap-4

i wanna remove the next and previous arrows on images if there is only one image
[image]

```
                <Col md={6}>
                    <Carousel>
                        {product.image ?  
                            <Carousel.Item>
                                <img
                                className="d-block w-100"
                                src={product.image}
                                style={{width:'540px', height:'480px'}}
                                />
                            </Carousel.Item> : 

                            <Carousel.Item>
                                <img
                                className="d-block w-100"
                                src={product.image}
                                style={{width:'540px', height:'480px'}}
                                />
                            </Carousel.Item>
                        }

                        {product.imageSecond ?  
                            <Carousel.Item>
                                <img
                                className="d-block w-100"
                                src={product.imageSecond}
                                style={{width:'540px', height:'480px'}}
                                />
                            </Carousel.Item> : 

                            null
                        }

                        {product.imageThird ?  
                            <Carousel.Item>
                                <img
                                className="d-block w-100"
                                src={product.imageThird}
                                style={{width:'540px', height:'480px'}}
                                />
                            </Carousel.Item> : 

                            null
                        }

                        {product.imageFourth ?  
                            <Carousel.Item>
                                <img
                                className="d-block w-100"
                                src={product.imageFourth}
                                style={{width:'540px', height:'480px'}}
                                />
                            </Carousel.Item> : 

                            null
                        }

                        {product.imageFifth ?  
                            <Carousel.Item>
                                <img
                                className="d-block w-100"
                                src={product.imageFifth}
                                style={{width:'540px', height:'480px'}}
                                />
                            </Carousel.Item> : 

                            null
                        }

                        {product.imageSixth ?  
                            <Carousel.Item>
                                <img
                                className="d-block w-100"
                                src={product.imageSixth}
                                style={{width:'540px', height:'480px'}}
                                />
                            </Carousel.Item> : 

                            null
                        }

                        {product.imageSeventh ?  
                            <Carousel.Item>
                                <img
                                className="d-block w-100"
                                src={product.imageSeventh}
                                style={{width:'540px', height:'480px'}}
                                />
                            </Carousel.Item> : 

                            null 
                        }

                    </Carousel>

                    </Col>
```

i tried to do it using DOM but it didnt work becuase it shows class is undefined.
I am not really good with css and DOM

i want  images to have these arrows and bottom indicators only if there are two or more images
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Rather than using an object to store images as properties (`imageFirst`, `imageSecond` etc) you should use an array  and `map` over it to produce the HTML. That way you can check if there's only one image because `array.length` will be 1.

Comment: still is there any way i can do it like using dom or somthing???

Answer (score 0):

```
const imagesArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('.d-block.w-100')]
if(imagesArray.length === 1){
    const leftArrow = document.querySelector('.carousel-control-prev-icon')
    const rightArrow = document.querySelector('.carousel-control-next-icon')

    leftArrow.style.hidden = true
    rightArrow.style.hidden = true
}
```